# Dynamically generated URL and Content page

Tags: templates, url-rewriting, query

I am in need of some advice. I have a section on my home page dynamically pulling in a list of terms from a custom table in the WP db. I have made a unique custom URL for each of these terms based on test code:

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/test-directory/test-code/<?php echo $record->test_code; ?>">
```

This works fine. My next step is to have these URLs, when clicked, load the accompanying dynamic content into a template. I tried the code below to create rewrite rules to point to a template but it just isn't working. It doesn't load the template but the default blog template. I am using a child theme but this should work:

```
function my_add_query_vars( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'test-directory';
        $qvars[] = 'test-code';
        return $qvars;
}

add_action('query_vars', 'my_add_query_vars');


function my_add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $newrules = array();
    $new_rules['^test-directory/(.*)/(.*)'] = 'index.php?test-directory=$matches[1]test-code=$matches[2]';
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_add_rewrite_rules');

function my_template_redirect() {
    if( get_query_var('test-code') ) {
        include_once(locate_template('template-faq-fullwidth.php', true));
        exit();
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect','template_redirect');
```

Any help is appreciated as always.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't forget to always flush your rewrite rules by going to **Settings -> Permalinks** and just clicking on **Save Changes**

Now on your problem, it seems that you're missing an '`&`' in your query:

`$new_rules['^test-directory/(.*)/(.*)'] = 'index.php?test-directory=$matches[1]&test-code=$matches[2]';`

Notice the `&` after `$matches[1]`

On the other hand, your 'template_redirect' action is not calling the correct function
(`template_redirect` instead of `my_template_redirect`)